# Generator of spatial translation in field theory

Tags: momentum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, classical-field-theory

In classical mechanics, we know that the momentum operator is the generator of spatial translation. But it seems to me that this is no longer the case in the classical field theory.

Lets first consider the energy-stress tensor of a classical field  given by (Goldstein p569):
$${T_\mu}^\nu=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\eta_{\rho,\nu}}\eta_{\rho,\nu}-\mathcal{L}{\delta_\mu}^\nu.$$

When $\nu=\mu=0$, then $$\mathcal{H} = {T_0}^0$$ is the hamiltonian density, whose 3d spatial integral is the total hamiltonian $H$. The hamiltonian $H$ is the generator of temporal evolution. That is if we know the initial state of the system, any observable $O$ at a later time could be obtained by calculating the Poisson bracket between $O$ and $H$.

The problem that I am dealing with, which is very similar to the time evolution of the field, is the spatial evolution of the field. That is: if we know the state of the field at plane $x=0$ at arbitrary time $t$, how do we calculate the rest of the field ($x>0$). To me, this problem is identical to the time evolution problem that we already considered since the spatial axis $x$ is equivalent to the time axis $t$. Therefore I believe the generator $G$ of spatial evolution along the x-direction should be given by the 3d integral (along $t,y,z$) of ${T_1}^1$:

$$G = \int dtdydz{T_1}^1.$$

To me, $G$ does not seem to be the total $x$-momentum of the field, which is given by the 3d spatial integral of ${T_1}^0$. In other words, the generator of spatial evolution is not the total momentum operator.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: You have an unsound theory that's clearly absurd, namely that your *G* generates spacial translations, failing in the face of hard evidence. The canonical nontrivial commutation relation underlying   motions is $\{\phi(x),\partial_0 \phi(y)\}\propto \delta (x-y)$. You know the correct answer from books, but you are still clinging to a baseless personal expectation ("I believe ... should").

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the $x^1$-momentum density is $T^{10}=T^{01}$, which is the generator of $x^1$-space translations. The $T^{11}$-component is instead pressure, cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor).